# SharePoint Site with SharePoint 2010 End User Documentation

Tags: training

Does anyone know where I can find some documentation I can import into our slowly developing SharePoint 2010 deployment so our end users will be able to learn the basics about list, libraries, versions, and so on?  I found something for SharePoint 2007 on Microsoft's website ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=673dc932-626a-4e59-9dca-16d685600a51 ) but I haven't found anything free for SharePoint 2010.

**Update**

I need the content and not SLK.

Comment: Have a look at http://slk.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Check [SharePoint 2010 Productivity Hub](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4aaa9862-e420-4331-8bc3-469d7bae0ff1):

> The Productivity Hub is a Microsoft
>   SharePoint Server 2010 site collection
>   that offers training materials for
>   end-users.